# Simple RewriteRule with no variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change a single URL on mysite from sitename.com/test123.php to sitename.com/article-about-stuff. There are no variables to consider, just a one-off URL change. Is this possible with mod_rewrite and RewriteRule? I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article-about-stuff$ /test123.php [L,QSA]
```

At the moment the user is redirected, but the url is changed to `test123.php`.  I want to keep the url.

I would also like to be able to redirect any traffic to `test123.php` to `/article-about-stuff` 
How can I simply write out the destination URL and link to it with the prettier URL?

Comment: What you have would work.. what's the problem?

Comment: the URL still is outputted as : sitename.com/test123.php

Comment: I am able to link to the page with sitename.com/article-about-stuff , but I am also able to access the page as sitename.com/test123.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the following directive to your .htaccess (this will redirect request from test123 to article-about...)

```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
   RewriteRule ^test123\.php$ /article-about-stuff [NC,R=301,L]
```

Note: the first condition assure that no previous redirection is made (to prevent redirection loop)

Comment: This should go above his rule, too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes, it's possible," but I'm not sure why you need `mod_rewrite` for such a simple redirect.

```
RedirectMatch ^test123\.php$ /test123.php
```

See [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite).